# Using JS in GoogleTagManager to change HTML code

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have to send event from Google Tag Manager, but not to Google Analytics (I know how to do this), but to application of my employer.

I can do this by editing the html code, but I was told to do this using only the Google Tag Manager.

When I am adding this line:

```
<a href="http://examplewww.pl/shop/" onclick="example('event.name_your_event_here')">...</a>
```

to html, for example:

```
div class="btn btn-primary btn-md outline">
  <a href="http://examplewww.pl/shop/" onclick="example('event.name_your_event_here')"/a>
```

it works. But when I tried to write script in javascript, it doesn't work.
My script:

```
var a = document.getElementByClass('btn btn-primary btn-md outline')
.getElementsByTagName('a'),
a.href += 'onclick="example('event.name_your_event_here')"';
```

Could you help me? I am not a programmer, so I cannot even know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean

```
var a = document.querySelector('.btn-primary>a');
a.onclick=function() { example('event.name_your_event_here') }
```

OR if you want to fix your version since it is document.getElementsByClassName which returns a collection like getElementsByTagName("a") does :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary btn-md outline')[0]
  .getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
  .onclick=function() { example('event.name_your_event_here') }
```

PS:

`<a href="http://examplewww.pl/shop/" onclick="example('event.name_your_event_here')"/a>`

is also not correct. You likely meant

`<a href="http://examplewww.pl/shop/" onclick="example('event.name_your_event_here')">Some text</a>`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, you saved me! :D